# How to sort the arraylist of Geopoints based on the nearest distance in android maps?

Tags: java, android, maps, openstreetmap

I have an Arraylist of customer locations with lat/lng values,i need to travel from the nearest customer  from my location and proceed based on the nearest located customers from then. how to sort the array of geopoints based on their distnace?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: refer here..https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1

Answer (score 0):

Create Java comparator from code snippet below, and then sort the ArrayList using the same.

Sample code to get distance between 2 geo locations

```
private double distanceBetween(final GeoLocation from, final GeoLocation to) {
    // double earthRadius = 3958.75; // in miles, change to 6371 for
    // kilometer output
    final double earthRadius = 6371;

    final double dLat = Math.toRadians(to.lattitude - from.lattitude);
    final double dLng = Math.toRadians(to.longitude - from.longitude);

    final double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
    final double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);

    final double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(from.lattitude))
        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(to.lattitude));

    final double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

    final double dist = earthRadius * c;
    return dist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) for your purpose.

Inside a Loop and based on the mode of transport use the Distance Matrix API to get the distance and the duration for you to reach them.

Based on the duration, use any sorting technique to sort the array list.

Finding the distance between the two lat and long's directly works if you're flying.